# Configurações do alert do javascript

Tags: javascript

Existem outras formas de mudar a exibição do alert? por exemplo quando eu uso o `\n` ele quebra a linha, gostaria de saber se existem outros **comandos** desses que eu possa modificar a visualização de texto, por exemplo deixar uma frase em negrito e etc

```
alert('Texto\n Linha de baixo');
```

Sei que poderia usar um alert personalizado usando `divs` e tal, mas tive essa curiosidade mesmo sobre o `alert()`

### Exemplo interessantíssimo

```js
alert('Error:\n\n\tPrint plugin is loaded but NOT active!');
```

Percebem que o texto `Print plugin is loaded but NOT active!` fica com uma formatação diferente

Comment: Não seria melhor criar uma `dialog` personalizada?

Comment: @FelipeAvelar sim seria melhor, mas tenho curiosidade sobre isso mesmo ;)

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha, também fiquei curioso, mas pesquisando parece que não se aplica nenhum tipo de estilos ao `alert` nativo, conforme informado [nesta pergunta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451873/change-alert-message-text-color-using-javascript).

Comment: Boa pergunta! Eu *acho* que não dá pra fazer muita coisa, não, e dou graças aos céus por isso (as funções `alert`, `confirm` e `prompt` deviam ser extintas, elas são um pesadelo pra segurança e pra usabilidade...).

Comment: @Fernando e @mgibsonbr Olha que interessante o exemplo que encontrei, cliquem em executar trecho do código o texto do `alert` fica com uma cor diferente

Comment: Acredito que não exista nenhum comando para o `alert`, o `\n` é convertido para um **caracter** de quebra de linha ao colocar em uma string, ou seja, o `alert` apenas exibe a string, sem formatar nada.

Comment: Você pode utilizar outros caracteres especiais que são convertidos ao utilizar em uma string, como por exemplo o caracter de tabulação `\t` ou até mesmo ícones, como `\u2605`. `alert("teste \u2605\n\tlegal");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O `alert` é uma janela de texto "puro", ou seja, linguagens de marcação não irão funcionar, muito menos de estilo. Existem alguns códigos de escape de texto. Como você citou o `\n` que quebra a linha.

Outros caracteres de escape:

- `\b`: backspace (U+0008 BACKSPACE)
- `\f`: Novo form (U+000C FORM FEED)
- `\n`: Nova linha (U+000A LINE FEED)
- `\r`: Retorno de carro (U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN)
- `\t`: Tabulação Horizontal (U+0009 CHARACTER TABULATION)
- `\v`: Tabulação Vertical(U+000B LINE TABULATION)
- `\0`: Carácter nulo (U+0000 NULL)

---

```js
function ola_b(){var str = 'Hello \bWorld'; alert(str); console.log(str);};
function ola_f(){var str = 'Hello \fWorld'; alert(str); console.log(str);};
function ola_n(){var str = 'Hello \nWorld'; alert(str); console.log(str);};
function ola_r(){var str = 'Hello \rWorld'; alert(str); console.log(str);};
function ola_t(){var str = 'Hello \tWorld'; alert(str); console.log(str);};
function ola_v(){var str = 'Hello \vWorld'; alert(str); console.log(str);};
function ola_0(){var str = 'Hello \0World'; alert(str); console.log(str);};
```

```html
<button onclick="return ola_b()">Alert \b</button>
<button onclick="return ola_f()">Alert \f</button>
<button onclick="return ola_n()">Alert \n</button>
<button onclick="return ola_r()">Alert \r</button>
<button onclick="return ola_t()">Alert \t</button>
<button onclick="return ola_v()">Alert \v</button>
<button onclick="return ola_0()">Alert \0</button>
```

---

Isso também depende do motor javascript do browser, fiz alguns testes e as mensagens ficaram melhores apresentadas no IE11 do que no Chrome42.

---

Confesso que vários eu nunca utilizei, nem sei para que serve.

Você pode ler mais sobre eles [aqui <sup>en</sup>](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes).

Comment: Aqui (Chrome, OSX), os 2 últimos exemplos mostram "Hello World", como se o caractere de controle não existisse.

Comment: Sim @bfavaretto, fiz uma edição ali falando que o IE11 interpreta os códigos melhores que o Chrome. O último `\0` ele some com a string, o penúltimo o Chrome quebra a linha e o IE11 não faz nada...

Answer (score 3):

O `alert` apenas exibe a string dada, sem formatar nada. O que acontece é que o próprio javascript interpreta alguns caracteres especiais em uma string. Os mais comuns são `\n` (quebra de linha) e `\t` (tabulação), mas não se restringe a isso.

Você pode inclusive utilizar qualquer caracter UTF-8 utilizando `\uX`, onde `X` é o código do caracter desejado, como por exemplo, `\u2605` (★).

Por esse comportamento não ser ligado ao `alert` e sim a linguagem (todas as linguagens que conheço suportam caracteres especiais), você pode utilizar este comportamento em outras funções também, como no `console.log`.

```js
alert("teste \u2605\n\tlegal");
```

```js
console.log("teste \u2605\n\tlegal");
```